# Unable to remove columns based on data-type using Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, power-query

I am trying to automate a load process and want to know if it is possible to perform column wise operations in Excel Power Query. Specifically I want to know how to either keep or discard columns based on data-type. I know how to use Choose Columns and Remove Columns on the menu but this is a little bit more specific then what those two options can do.

I haven't learned the M language yet but welcome M solutions which I can learn from.

I tried looking online and through Power-Query related SuperUser questions but did not find any answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for Table.ColumnsOfType which might be useful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260753.aspx

For example you could embed that in a Table.RemoveColumns function, e.g. (assuming your prior step was "Changed Type"

`= Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",Table.ColumnsOfType(#"Changed Type", {type number}) )`

You can get the Power Query UI to help write this - just use it to Remove a Column, then edit the resulting Step's formula to look like the example above.